# Could not load file or assembly exception, only on other machines

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently working on a program in C# WPF. I use an external dll called Irrklang. It's made for x86 only so I set VS to compile for x86. I added the reference, set the copy local to true and set the dll as Required in the application files.

When publishing the app using clickonce I upload it. I install on two machines: my dev machine and another machine. On my dev machine things work fine. On the other machine I get the could not load file or assembly exception through my error handling I added to my app. In the event log there is a xamlparse exception.

How can I solve this when everything works fine on my dev machine. I tried Dependencywalker but that doesn't show anything and I made sure the dll is in the folder of the executable. I ask this question again here on stackoverflow, the last time someone made me an empty app with a reference to the dll and he installed it on 3 other machines and it worked fine. I published his app like I did with my own and it shows the exact same problem!

Please help me out

UPDATE: I was thinking about it but your comment beat me to it! :D I program .net 4 Extended and it is set as a prerequisite. VS C# Express 2010.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework / Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Oh - and by any chance is your Irrklang assembly GAC'ed on your dev machine?

Comment: Updated post, how can I check if it is GAC;ed?

Comment: Is the Irrklang your own assembly or someone else's?  If it's your own, you would have had to do work to register it in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache).  Also, did you browse to the .dll file to set a reference to it, or did you pick it from the long list of assemblies (that also includes all of the system assemblies)?

Comment: Someone else's. I browsed it, it's in the executable folder.

Comment: Hey, was there any resolution to this issue? I'm encountering the same problem, but inverse: Works ok 99% of computers, but a few throw this exact error. No platform differences, No Operating System differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no specific advice then.  It sounds like you just need to some old school trial and error... Whiddle the app down to something that will distribute correctly with ClickOnce and keep adding functionality until it doesn't!

Comment: That sounds great but where do I start if an even empty app with just a dll reference already gives me this exception...

Comment: Does it publish without the dll reference?

Comment: Yes is also publishes with dll reference but as soon as I do anything with code from that dll it gives the exception. On the dev machine it works on both occassions though